# Regarding the tag info for the 'aliens' tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

The tag info for the [aliens](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) tag states:

> For questions about a different and uncharacteristic species or
> object that has come to the world from another world. NOT for
> questions about extraterrestrials in their native environment.

This excerpt (particularly the second sentence) does not seem to align with the current usage of the tag, and to me personally, does not make much sense. In its current iteration, there does not seem to be a tag for questions dealing with extra-terrestrials in their native environment, as the only two relevant tags are [aliens](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) and [xenobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenobiology), both of which currently specifically exclude such questions.

A better excerpt in my opinion would simply be something like "*For questions dealing with extra-terrestrial life*".

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you edit in a digest of how the tag is currently understood? Frankly, I don't really like how this tag is worded.

Comment: @elemtilas as in, describe the kind of questions I see using the tag?

Comment: Yes please! Just a quick synopsis of what you've noticed with a couple supporting links!

Comment: In addition to the improvements @elemtilas has suggested to the question, please (a) add to the question the current full summary and wiki descriptions as quotations (using ">"). And (b) post an answer proposing complete replacements for the summary and the description. This will make it simpler to discover community concensus about the proposal and to allow others with differing views to post their alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Wiki tag for Xenobiology - this line (to me) is the differentiating factor:

> Questions about biology-related aesthetics or environmental interaction should use the creature-design tag.

That would/should cover any questions about non-human life in it's native environment, whether it be Fantasy, Alien or other.

That said...

If I was writing a question and it was about alien species on an alien world - guess which tag I would use?

And so whilst the wording and descriptions are 'correct', I agree with your fundamental point - that these tags should be re-written to better align with their real-world usage, even if there is a logical reason why there is a difference.